# Unable to clear array and string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arrays

I have a following program, it takes strings from 4 textboxes and puts them into array and displays the message(created from the array) after user clicks on btnOK. I have a button called btnClear which if clicked should clear both the message string and array but it's not doing it and I'm not quite sure why, can someone have a look and advise.

```
string[,] namesTable = new string[10, 4];
int row = 0;
string message = "";

private void btnOK_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  namesTable[row, 0] = txtFirstName.Text;
  namesTable[row, 1] = txtSurname.Text;
  namesTable[row, 2] = txtPosition.Text;
  namesTable[row, 3] = txtComment.Text;
  row++;

  message = "Name.\tSurname\tPosition\tComment\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < namesTable.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
    if (namesTable[i, 0] != null)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < namesTable.GetLength(1); j++)
      {
        message += namesTable[i, j] + "\t";
      }
      message += "\n";
    }
  }

  MessageBox.Show(message, "Names Table");
}

private void btnClear_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Array.Clear(namesTable, 0, 4);
    message = "";
}
```

If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of cleared elements wrap from row to row in a multi-dimensional array therefore
You should use:

```
Array.Clear(namesTable, 0, 40);
//                      ^  ^
//                      |  |_The number of elements to clear.
//                      |
//                      |____The starting index of the range of elements to clear.
```

Comment: @fadjad Can you explain, why when I have it set to 4 and do following: 1) enter 4 values, click OK, 2)click OK again 3)click Clear 4) click OK again Message box still shows second row and third?

Comment: Because in your code: `Array.Clear(namesTable, 0, 4);` only sets `namesTable[0, 1]` through `namesTable[0, 4]` zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing 4 values in the array from index 0. However, your insert code inserts at the `row` index. This is likely to be your problem. What is the value of `row` ?

To clear everyting in the array, simply do:

```
namesTable = new string[10, 4];
row = 0;
```

Comment: row is automaticaly calculated - incremented when new "row" of data is created

Comment: Do you want to re-initalize all rows, or just the current one ? Under all circumstances, you will want to clear the correct portion of your array. If you need to clear everything just `new` a new array and set `row` to 0.

Comment: by "new a new array" do you mean clear existing one or something else?

Comment: Thank you it works too but I can only select one correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all your data, so reinitialize all:

```
private void btnClear_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.namesTable = new string[10, 4];
    this.row = 0;
    this.message = "";
}
```